# gridview disappears after changing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that should split into pages but the issue is that when I change the page the whole gridview is disappearing I tried everything I found in the internet but with no solution here is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="ExistContents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"    OnPageIndexChanging="ExistContents_PageIndexChanging" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentID" HeaderText="id" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="TmpFilename" HeaderText="Image">
            <ControlStyle Height="64px" Width="96px" />
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentID" HeaderText="id" Visible="false" ShowHeader="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChBox1"  OnCheckedChanged="ExistContents_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  CssClass="header"/>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is the event handler

```
protected void ExistContents_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{        
    ExistContents.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    List<CONTENT> panier;
    panier = (List<CONTENT>)Session["PANIER"];
    ExistContents.DataSource = panier;
    ExistContents.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: set the propety in your GV ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"  what happens, does it have data when you change page ?

Comment: it  shows only the header without data rows but i found a solution to the probleme actually it was my mistake i should make the linq query in my eventhandler as the data source of my viewgrid thank you for yours help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an answer for this probleme, acctually my datasource was not the session but a linq query so i changed it and it works perfectly

and here is my new code

```
        protected void ExistContents_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
        int id= Convert.ToInt32(gr.Cells[0].Text);
        if (chk.Checked)
            AddToCaddy(id, "DELETE");
        else
            DeleteFromCaddy(id);

        UpdatePanel.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

just for information if you are making a databind to your gridview in the Page_Load inside the `if (!IsPostBack)` then you will need to redefind the dataSource but if you'r not then you only need to use these functions

`UpdatePanel.DataBind();
   UpdatePanel.Update();`

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the [`PageIndexChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged) event instead.

The [`pageIndexChanging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging) is made to give you an option to cancel the paging before it's executed.

Comment: as i said i found the answer it's in my comment but thank you anyway

Comment: please post an answer to your own question so other people might benefit from it as well.